# Admin rights are not passed to C++ library

Tags: c#, c++, admin-rights

I have a C# app that exports a series of WCF services (It requires admin rights in order to do this). From this app i am using a C++ DLL in order to do some operations with an external hardware and this library outputs a series of files in my app folder location. The app resides in C:\Program Files.

However the admin rights are not passed to the C++ library and this library is not managing to create the output files. If i run from another location (eg: D:\Test) it runs perfectly.

How it is possible that the admin rights are not passed to the C++ library ? Is there a way i can fix this without changing the output directory ?

Comment: Did you run the actual app as administrator?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad : Yes, the C# app is started with admin rights